# Getting List of Pipelines Authorized to Use an Environment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

In the Azure DevOps user interface, one can edit the list of Pipelines that are authorized to use a Service Endpoint (aka Service Connection). This list can be retrieved from the API using:

GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{id}/resources](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/build/definitions/%7Bid%7D/resources)

which lists resources that the pipeline is authorized to use.

All I see in pipelines' resources are "endpoint"s (Service Connections) and "queue"s (Agent Pool, I guess). But not Environments. We absolutely have Environments that specific Pipelines are authorized to use.

How do I get this information using the Azure DevOps REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll admit, this is not very intuitive. I've done this a handful of times and it took me a bit to remember how exactly to do this. The documentation for this is under "Distributed Task".

The endpoint you are looking for is [Pipeline Permissions - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/pipeline-permissions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP):

```bash
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/pipelinepermissions/{resourceType}/{resourceId}?api-version=7.0-preview.1
```

In your case, the `resourceType` should be `environment` and the `resourceId` should be the ID of the environment you want to query for.

To query for IDs of your environments, you will need to the use the [Environments - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/environments/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) endpoint. Be careful with the term "environment" in Azure DevOps as there is a legacy "Release Environment" and the modern "Pipeline Environment". The link I put for the list environments endpoint is for the Pipeline Environments.